# Getting error while defining schema for csv file in spark using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to define schema to CSV file using `case class` in Scala.

```
case class userSchema(name : String,
                      place : String,
                      designation : String)
object userProcess {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Spark_processing for Hbase").master("yarn").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  val colNames = classOf[userSchema].getDeclaredFields.map(f=> f.getName)
    val file = spark.read.option("inferSchema", false).option("header", false).csv("D:\\wSapce\\User.csv").toDF(colNames:_*).as(userSchema)

}
```

But in last line(for value file) I am getting below compile time error:

```
overloaded method value as with alternatives: (alias: Symbol)org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] <and> (alias: String)org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] <and> [U](implicit evidence$2: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[U])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U] cannot be applied to (tavant.user.userSchema.type)
```

Any Idea why I am getting this error...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue lies in the below line:

```
val file = spark.read.option("inferSchema", false).option("header", false).csv("D:\\wSapce\\User.csv").toDF(colNames:_*).as(userSchema)
```

spark.read.option().csv - will return the DataFrame. You don't need toDF() again, to convert to DataFrame.

You can convert the DataFrame to Dataset with defined scehma(case class) using as(userSchema) method as below:

```
val file = spark.read.option("inferSchema", false).option("header", false).csv("D:\\wSapce\\User.csv").as(userSchema)
```

Comment: Yes correct but need a little more editing, Sqaure brackets for 'as'
val file = spark.read.option("inferSchema", false).option("header", false).csv("D:\\wSapce\\User.csv").as[userSchema]

Comment: Oh yeah.. missed it. Thanks :)